# Building a pyramid of letters in C99

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FINISH 'Z'
int main(void){
    int spacenm, currentspacenm, i;
    char ini, inirecord;
    int rownm, currentrownm;
    printf("PLease enter a random uppercase letter: ");
    scanf("%c", &inirecord);
    spacenm = rownm = FINISH - inirecord;
    for (i = 0; i<= spacenm; i++)
        printf(" ");
    printf("%c\n", inirecord);
    i = 0;
    for (currentrownm = 1; currentrownm <= rownm; currentrownm ++){
        for (currentspacenm = 1; currentspacenm <= spacenm; currentspacenm++)
            printf(" ");
        spacenm--;
        for (ini = inirecord; ini<=inirecord+i; ini++)
            printf("%c", ini);
        i++;
        for (; ini>=inirecord; ini--)
            printf("%c", ini);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wonder if there're better ways where less variables are needed or less redundant code structure is used to improve efficiency.

Comment: In cases of making improvements in working code, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place. :)

Comment: Please try explaining what does your code do. Also, try explaining what all methods you have tried and show your research.

Comment: You should check that the input succeeded and got an upper-case letter.  Look at the return value from `scanf()` — it should be `1`; change the format string to `" %c"` (blank before the `%c`); use functions from `<ctype.h>`.  Personally, I'd use `putchar()` to output single characters; that doesn't seem to be as widely used as it used to be.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, cuz I'm really a beginner so have little knowledge about conventions in C etc. Anyways you answers were all quite helpful.

Comment: @Francis.Tricka Should the first row contain only one letter? That is what output should be if the entered letter is 'Z'?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Is there any benefit in using `ctype.h` functions like `isupper()` instead of just `c>='A' && c<='Z'`?

Comment: The benefits are usually more theoretical than practical, but…if your computer uses [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) then the test on `A`..`Z` picks up non-alpha characters too.  The advantage of `A`..`Z` on systems based on ASCII (most of them except IBM mainframes) is that it doesn't pick up accented alphabetic characters, whereas if you use `setlocale()`, the `<ctype.h>` functions (macros) might map more characters as `isupper()` than you expected.  If you don't use `setlocale()`, that is unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yeah that's what it suppose to do, like to build a pyramid based on your input, and for the last row the letters are printed all the way to 'Z' and back to the 'inirecord'.

Answer (score 0):

We beginners should help each other.:)

There is no check in your program relative to whether the user input is valid.

Also if I'm not mistaken not all coding tables as for example the EBCDIC table contain sequentially upper letters.

There is no need to write a separate snippet of code to output the first row of the pyramid as you are doing

```
for (i = 0; i<= spacenm; i++)
    printf(" ");
printf("%c\n", inirecord);
```

Using formating you can eliminate the number of loops.

Take into account that in general instead of this format specification

```
scanf("%c", &inirecord);
      ^^^^
```

you should use the following

```
scanf(" %c", &inirecord);
      ^^^^^
```

Otherwise control characters will be also read.

Here are my three cents.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char *letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    const size_t N = strlen( letters );

    while ( 1 )
    {
        char alpha[3];
        _Bool exit_status;
        const char *p;

        do
        {
            printf( "PLease enter a random uppercase letter (Enter - exit ): " );
            exit_status = fgets( alpha, sizeof( alpha ), stdin ) == NULL || alpha[0] == '\n'; 

            if ( !exit_status ) 
            {
                p = NULL;
                if ( alpha[1] == '\n' )
                {
                    alpha[0] = toupper( ( unsigned char )alpha[0] );
                    p = strchr( letters, alpha[0] );
                }
            }
        } while ( !exit_status && !p );     

        if ( exit_status ) break;

        int n = &letters[N] - p;

        putchar( '\n' );
        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%*c", n - i, alpha[0] );
            int j = 0;
            while ( j != i ) putchar( p[++j] );
            while ( j != 0 ) putchar( p[--j] );
            putchar( '\n' );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
PLease enter a random uppercase letter (Enter - exit ): Z

Z

PLease enter a random uppercase letter (Enter - exit ): Y

 Y
YZY

PLease enter a random uppercase letter (Enter - exit ): X

  X
 XYX
XYZYX

PLease enter a random uppercase letter (Enter - exit ): A

                         A
                        ABA
                       ABCBA
                      ABCDCBA
                     ABCDEDCBA
                    ABCDEFEDCBA
                   ABCDEFGFEDCBA
                  ABCDEFGHGFEDCBA
                 ABCDEFGHIHGFEDCBA
                ABCDEFGHIJIHGFEDCBA
               ABCDEFGHIJKJIHGFEDCBA
              ABCDEFGHIJKLKJIHGFEDCBA
             ABCDEFGHIJKLMLKJIHGFEDCBA
            ABCDEFGHIJKLMNMLKJIHGFEDCBA
           ABCDEFGHIJKLMNONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
          ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
         ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
        ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
       ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
      ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
     ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA

PLease enter a random uppercase letter (Enter - exit ):
```

Comment: "We beginners"? You have 133k rep and a gold badge in both C and C++ LOL

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I never in my life wrote for example a C++ program.:) I have no job. So I am a beginner.

Comment: well that's not the definition of beginner, but ok, ahah

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Well thanks man. I gotta say your program looks awesome and contains codes that I'm not yet up to... So later on as I progress more I'll definitely come around and learn your code. Another kinda trivial question: since I'm doing this with a book and this 'pyramid' thing comes from an appended exercise question, so I wonder if there's an easier way to do it based on my code (specifically how to replace the two awkward for loop with one single smart loop that gives the correct first row output)?

Comment: @Francis.Tricka Just consider the loops im my program         for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%*c", n - i, alpha[0] );
            int j = 0;
            while ( j != i ) putchar( p[++j] );
            while ( j != 0 ) putchar( p[--j] );
            putchar( '\n' );
        } and try to adjust your loops this way.

Comment: Fine, I'll try it. Thanks Vlad